# Have you ever been expelled or deported from the Federal Republic of Germany, or been refused entry into the Federal Republic of Germany?

Tags: visa, germany

I have applied twice for Germany seeking visa and got rejected twice for some reasons like i did not dealt with Germany market and I have not complete my master degree.

Do I have to answer this question as Yes with give explanation of the rejection or just answer with only" Yes"

Comment: See: [schengen - I have been deported from Germany? Can l apply for study Visa in UK - Travel Stack Exchange](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/177508/95267)

Answer (score 3):

No, visa refusal is not the same as being denied entry or deported.

Entry is denied at the point of entry, at the border crossing or airport immigration.

Deportation is you being forceably removed by the law enforcement from within Germany.

Comment: Denial of entry is _possible_ even with a visa. Obviously without a visa it is much more likely.

Comment: @gnasher729 how is it relevant to the question or the answer?